# Future of mirrors in Dart

Tags: plugins, module, dart, dart-mirrors

I am developing an app in Dart and I plan to support dynamically loaded plugins. I can't do this in mirrors as it does no support instantiating classes from external sources, listing classes from external files etc. Do you plan to extend mirrors to  support java like reflections?
Thank you, Skoky.

Comment: This actually isn't a platform for asking for the future plans of Dart I guess. And some sort of java reflection mechanisms are already available. I guess you are searching for something like class loader?

Comment: You can do this without mirrors. Arbitrary code loading is done via Isolate.spawnUri(), this can load a source file into a new isolate. Communication with the plugin code in the isolate must be done via the message passing api. I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for Mirrors to support arbitrary code loading, as this has huge performance, and security implications.

Answer (score 2):

It was discussed several times but I think it is not decided. What was mentioned as argument against this feature is security which is taken very seriously especially in the browser but of course there are advantages and not having this feature limits the possibilties of Dart.

What you can currently do is launching additional isolates from external code files. This is currently cumbersome in the browser because an isolate in the browser doesn't provide access to not only the DOM but any browser API which is extremely limiting. But as I understand there are improvements planned or maybe already work in progress.

Comment: Just noticed this: [spawnDomUri](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html#id_spawnDomUri).